# Is there a way to scroll the toolbar icons of an application?

Tags: macos

On a 24" display, there is enough space to display all the toolbar icons of my applications.

But on the MacBook 13" display some of them are not displayed.

Is there a way to scroll the tools bar in order to see the entire set of icons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [AccessMenubarApps](http://www.ortisoft.de/en/accessmenubarapps/) which works on the basic principle of temporarily replacing the current menubar with a shorter one to allow all the menubar icons to be visible. It can be accessed by clicking on the icon, via mouse gestures, or a configurable hotkey.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are looking for (not a scrolling solution), but you could have a look at [Bartender](http://www.macbartender.com/). By putting the least important icons in there, and leaving the most important ones in place, you could have 2 levels of icons, hopefully giving enough real estate to display all of them in your 13" display.